# I don't manage to configure volumes in docker-compose to have a folder reachable by dockerized pgAdmin, to restore a database

Tags: docker-compose, pgadmin, docker-volume, pgadmin-4

I have setup from a [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/postgresql_docker/) a pgadmin4 container and a PostgreSQL container with the following `docker-compose`:

```
version: "2"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
    - db-data:/opt/docker/pgadmin4/postgresql/data
    - /home/laurent/Documents/Informatique/Docker/sample-database:/opt
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
   
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@linuxhint.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    - /home/laurent/Documents/Informatique/Docker/sample-database:/opt
    links:
    - "db:pgsql-server"
volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

In both conainers, I have mounted the path `/home/laurent/Documents/Informatique/Docker/sample-database` where I have put a [sample database](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/dvdrental.zip).

After having created the *dvdrental* database as explained in the [tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-getting-started/load-postgresql-sample-database/), I try to import it with `restore`, but I cannot find my `/opt/dvdrental.tar` as expected.
When I *Select file*, I get this:

[image]

If I add `opt` in the path and refresh, nothing more.

But if I open a console in both containers, I have `/opt/dvdrental.tar`.

[image]

What do I miss?

Comment: The second tutorial you link to starts off by describing a path using `psql` to load the database.  You should be able to use this from your host system directly; you do not need to mount any host content into any containers and you do not need PGAdmin (unless you want it, of course).  It will connect to the `ports:` of the database container.

Comment: (Make sure to mount the `db-data` named volume on the same directory as `PGDATA`.  `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is its default location and you do not need to state it explicitly.  The `links:` option is obsolete and you should be able to remove it without any adverse effects.)

Comment: Thanks all. I found the way-forward [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63717373/1344633). Could someone kindly set my question to duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169643/pgadmin4-import-file-error-cant-find-file)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The path in the pgadmin container is: `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/<login name>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pgAdmin4 import file error - can't find file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169643/pgadmin4-import-file-error-cant-find-file)